# responsive template joomla

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla 3.0 I want to create a responsive template , I am using gantry for that. [gantry](http://www.gantry-framework.org/)

I have my main menu, in gantry framework I activate posicion top and header, I put my menu in position header-a

But dont show me nothing. anyone know How work this framework, I saw all documentacion apparently is very easy

anyone know good documentacion to create a responsive template

Answer (score 0):

Gantry is a good choice for a responsive Joomla template.

It may not be obvious but you need to install RokNavMenu as the default menu system in Gantry.

It's a free download from the RocketTheme website.